# How to split one row into multiple row by test size and pattern snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one row which contains list of test separated by comma and I want to divide row into multiple rows by text size and pattern.

**Table**

```
user  oder_num
1     or-11, or-2, or-3, or-4, or-5, or-6
2     or-14, or-25, or-3, or-4, or-5, or-6
3     or-1, or-2, or-35, or-46, or-5, or-6
```

Expected output

```
1   or-11, or-2, or-3
1   or-4, or-5, or-6
2   or-14, or-25, or-3
2   or-4, or-5, or-6
3   or-1, or-2, or-35
3  or-46, or-5, or-6
```

split into 3 order each row.

Comment: Hi - please format your data as tables so that it is understandable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL gives you your expected output

```
with d as ( select '1' u, 'or-11, or-2, or-3, or-4, or-5, or-6' o
union all
select 2, 'or-14, or-25, or-3, or-4, or-5, or-6'
union all
select 3, 'or-1, or-2, or-35, or-46, or-5, or-6'
)
select u, trim(substr(o, 1, regexp_instr(o, '[,]', 1, 3) -1 )) c
from d
union all
select u, trim(substr(o, regexp_instr(o, '[,]', 1, 3) +1, length(o) ))
from d
order by 1
```